# SQLServerException: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'bounds'

Tags: sql, scala, azure-databricks

I am trying to run the following code. The idea is to obtains lower and upper bound of source table, based on a given ID column.

```
   %scala
    val bounds_sql = s"(select min(PersonID), max(PersonID) from dbo.persons) as bounds"
    val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    val (lower, upper) = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcString, bounds_sql, connectionProperties)
    .as[(Option[Long], Option[Long])].take(1).map { case (a, b) => (a.getOrElse(0L), b.getOrElse(0L)) }.head
```

However, what I am getting is:

```
SQLServerException: No column name was specified for column 1 of 'bounds'
```

And I am not really sure what the issue could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used Scala or Databricks - but I do use SQL Server so my answer is based on more generic approach.

I believe your issue lies in the statement

```
(select min(PersonID), max(PersonID) from dbo.persons) as bounds
```

You are creating a derived (virtual) table called 'bounds'. However, you have not named the columns of that table. I have two suggested approaches.

1. Name your columns e.g.,

```
(select min(PersonID) as bounds_lower, max(PersonID) as bounds_upper from dbo.persons) as bounds
```

PS beware calling them lower and upper as these are often SQL functions (converting to lower case and upper case respectively).

2. Do you need the derived table? If you just need data in order, try removing the 'bounds' alias

```
select min(PersonID), max(PersonID) from dbo.persons
```